# grid view count

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a web page wit Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <th bgcolor="#666666" style="color: #FFFFFF" align="center">
            aaa
        </th>
        <th bgcolor="#666666" style="color: #FFFFFF" align="center">
            bbbs
        </th>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hyp_dcisapp" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/DCIS_Approv.aspx" Font-Bold="True"
                ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="Small" text-decoration="none"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Dcisdelt")%></asp:HyperLink>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

finally
it `contains colums  aaa  bbb 
                     20   30

i have a link butoon in home page

```
asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="totalCount"
```

how i can display this linkbutton line  totalcount(50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like...

```
 LinkButton1.Text = "TotalCount (" + Repeater1.Items.Count.ToString() + ")";
```